# How to write the good xpath?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to write the good xpath? I want to get the text 'Test Employee'

```
 <div class="rowData">
 <img width="40" height="40"/>
 <b class="initials">TE</b>
 <div>Test Employee</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why does this question have two upvotes?

Comment: @olyv this is what i had in my mind. why people are giving upvotes for this type of effortless questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below:

```
//*[@class='rowData']//div
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell your devs to use ids and make everyone's life easier :-)

Then

```
<div id="employee_name">Test Employee</div>
```

Can be found with

```
//div[@id="employee_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try the xpath below:

```
//div[@class='rowData']/div/text()
```

Comment: This is a valid XPath, however it cannot be used with Selenium. InvalidSelectorException will throw